# Parsing simple json response from Volley

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am trying parse a JSON response from Volley.

My "response" parameter  is: 
`{"result":["{\"success\":\"false\"}"]}`

I am getting an error at: `JSONObject jo=ja.getJSONObject(0); //Error here`

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    JSONObject jo=ja.getJSONObject(0); //Error here
                    String rst=jo.getString("success");
                    if (rst.equals("true")) {
                             ///do something
                    } else{
                           ///do something
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: try logging variable ja

Comment: Hi, ja variable is: ["{\"success\":\"false\"}"]

Comment: Here is the exception: org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":"false"} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, your json array contains string not `JSONObject`. In your JSON `{"result":["{\"success\":\"false\"}"]}` the element `"{\"success\":\"false\"}"` is String, it means your `JSONArray` contains `Strings` not `JSONObject`. So you need to parse elements as `String` and then parse those to `JSONObject`.

---

You can write your code as

```
JSONArray ja = jb.getJSONArray("result");
for(int i=0; i<ja.length(); i++) {
      String stringElement = ja.getString(i);
      // Then you can parse it with JSONObject
      JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(stringElement);
}
```

---

FYI, the JSON you are expecting is `{"result":[{"success":"false"}]}`

Comment: Hi, I did:JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
                    String s=ja.get(0).toString();
                    JSONObject entries= new JSONObject(s);

                    String rst=entries.getString("success");
                    if (rst.equals("true")) {..................... and it works well.  But you are correct in your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject jo=ja.getJSONObject(0);
```

to this

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response)
JSONArray ja=j0.getJSONArray("result");
```

You have to create json Object from the response first.. Then get jsonarray from the JsonObject...